# Second monitor not coming back on after going into hibernate

Tags: display, hibernate

10 and a new problem has come up. When I my machine hibernates the second monitor does not come back on. I did not have this problem in 11.04.

The main monitor is plugged into a vga port, and the second plugged into a display port then an adapter to vga

the system is a Dell  Optiplex 790

and the graphics card is (according to lspci) a 
VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)

I am running the classic Gnome desktop though the problem occurs in Unity as well.

Answer (score 1):

Check the Monitor application, detect monitors and see if that works.

Comment: It did not when I just went detect displays. It does come back on when I turn mirroring on and off again, but that seems to be a bit of a pain. Any idea about a more permanent solution.